# Problems with char array

Tags: c++

I don't want to delete the first character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

char name[10][80]={0};int i;
int main (){
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"\nIngrese el nombre N "<<i+1<<": ";cin.getline(name[i],80);      
}
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(name[i]== '\0'){
    }else{
        cout<<"\nEl nombre ingresado es: "<<name[i];
    }
}
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

for some reason the first character is deleted when i print on screen

example: `Leo Gutierrez`

screen: `eo Gutierrez`

Comment: because you tell the program to `ignore` it

Comment: This shouldn't compile. You can't compare `'\0'` and an array. `'\0'` is not a null pointer constant, so there's no implicit conversion from it to a pointer to use.

Comment: any help? what i need to change in the code?

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
    `cin.ignore()`

you can try this:

```
while(iswspace(cin.peek())) cin.ignore();// eat white...
```

it is mean to skip any unseen character before the input

but this won't allow to enter empty string.

This will allow it:

```
while(iswspace(cin.peek()) && cin.peek()!=10)  cin.ignore();
```

means skip any unseen character except the enter key.

And name[i] is like address and it never equal to 0. so I guess you should check:

```
if(name[i][0]== '\0')
```